# Create a calendar in WPF Using MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Question: Create a Button for each day of current year and should display date of the current year and on clicking display day of the week.

Solution: 
View: Create 31 button 
View model: Bind button command and written logic to display day for all 31 buttons
Model: create 31 properties to Notify all button

Somebody provide me better approach for this?

Comment: Why dont you use the `Calender` control?

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you attempted either of the answers presented, and tried to modify them if they don't fit your precise needs?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an Itemscontrol and Uniform Grid together to do this rather than creating a 31 separate buttons. Have a look at [this](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/01/09/468-firstcolumn-property-allows-blank-cells-in-a-uniformgrid/) too.

view

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Day}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="5" Columns="7" FirstColumn="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button  Background="White" Content="{Binding date}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel

```
 public ObservableCollection<DayModel> Day
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Day = new ObservableCollection<DayModel>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
        {
            Day.Add(new DayModel
            {
                date=i+1
            });
        }
    }
```

and result

[image: your calender with buttons]

this example is just created to demonstrate you can do that.

Comment: My Question : I must need to create a button for each day of current year.Is it possible with Above solution.

Comment: you can use itemscontrol in itemscontrol. One itemscontrol for months - and another for days in month.

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhere this answer. Use ItemControl to bind buttoms. Item can provide different command for an each button. So your xaml would look like :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCommands}" Canvas.Bottom="525" Canvas.Left="52">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helperClasses:MyCommandWrapper}">
                <Button Content="{Binding SomeProperty}" Command="{Binding Command}" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">                  
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
```

You can add items to collection this way:

```
var temp = new MyCommandWrapper {Command = yourCommand, YourProperty = yourValue};
MyCommands.Add(temp);
```

YourCommand is usual ICommand.
Finally wrapper:

```
public class MyCommandWrapper
{
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    #region Properties

    public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }

    #endregion Properties

}
```

**Edit:**
You also need to create a collection. I usually do it so:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MyCommandWrapper> _commandWrapperCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyCommandWrapper>();

public ObservableCollection<MyCommandWrapper> MyCommands
    {
        get { return _commandWrapperCollection; }
        set
        {
            _commandWrapperCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But we need to create 31 buttons Correct? Why do we need 31 command ? plz explain it

Comment: You can run i cycle and create from code 31 buttons. If you want the same behavior for each buttonClick, then you can create only one command and pass it to each element in the collection. But also you have an opportunity to add to each button different behavior

Comment: And you do not need to create in xaml 31 separate button. You can create one style, and bind them from your viewModel

Comment: @Sudhir.net, it sounds like you want someone to write the whole program for you. You really need to make some attempt at writing it yourself based on the ideas presented.

Comment: @Sudhir.net I did it already. You just need to write a style for a button. Xaml code you can copy and paste. Then you need to modify wrapper class to your needs and add command collection.